# Error: read ECONNRESET-node:events:492 Nodejs Auto Disconnect problem

Tags: javascript, mysql, reactjs, node.js

My Server was lost connection sometime automatically.I don't know why this problem was coming!. I use database clone from another database if i use that previous database then it worked good but if i use the newest one then this problem came. Please help to fix it.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CaTJt.png)

I need to fix this solution

Comment: Please don't post images of code, data, error messages, etc. Copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text. For more information please see the Meta FAQ entry https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557